# How to find proper subsets containing certain elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reviewing some work and I am given:

Set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

I am supposed to find the subsets of $A$ containing at least the elements $1, 2,$ and $3.$

What is the formula I should use to find this? Thank you.

Edit: I should have clarified, I am needing to find the number of subsets.
Thank you everyone for the kind help. Have a good one!

Comment: Just use your common sense, and list out all the results would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes but there has to be some formula that returns the precise number without having to write it all out. Doing this with a more complex set would be time consuming.

Comment: Are you wanting to find the subsets themselves, or the number of subsets?  **Hint**, any subset of $A$ which contains all of $1,2,3$ can be written as the union of $\{1,2,3\}$ and a subset of $\{4,5,6\}$

Comment: @HarryDavoe But you are asking to list all the subset, instead of finding the number of subset. Hint: what's the number of subsets of {4,5,6}

Comment: Ah yes, I meant the number of subsets. Doing so with a six number set is simple but I am thinking more towards sets with many numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be rather simple when you realize that since $1$, $2$, and $3$ must be included in each subset, you should calculate the power set of $\left\{ 4,5,6 \right\}$ and then unite each subset element of the power set with $\left\{ 1,2,3 \right\}$.

So take $\emptyset ,
\left\{ 4 \right\},
\left\{ 5 \right\},
\left\{ 6 \right\},
\left\{ 4,5 \right\},
\left\{ 5,6 \right\},
\left\{ 4,6 \right\},
\left\{ 4,5,6 \right\}$ and start each one off with $1,2,3$.

Mathematically, one way we could express the set of all appropriate subsets of $\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \right\}$ as

$$\left\{ \left\{ 1,2,3 \right\} \cup S : S\in \wp\left( \left\{ 4,5,6 \right\} \right) \right\}$$

(I know this isn't the prettiest notation given the nested nature of these sets and my imperfect LaTeX skills, but hopefully this clears up some of your confusion.)

Comment: Okay, so it should just be 3! + 1(set A)?

Comment: @Harry no, factorials will not appear at all in the calculations here.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of element $N$, the number of all its subset is $2^N$.

So for each element, we could choose it in a subset, or choose it not in a subset - thus for each element, we have two choices when we make a subset.

Now we need to make N choices over each element, that is $2 \times 2 \times 2 ... \times 2 = 2^N$

For an example of $\{4,5,6\}$, when constructing a subset, we first decide if the subset has $4$ or not. So we have two choices over choosing $4$. Once we decided $4$, e.g., let's say we decide $4$ not in the subset, then we consider if we want $5$ to be in the subset or not - we again have two choices. Once we decided on $5$, e.g., let's decide $5$ in the subset, then we have two choices over $6$. If we decide $6$ to be in the subset, then we are done, and get the subset $\{5,6\}$.

For more information, and possibly discussion about infinite set, check for [power set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the number of sets that all contain $\{ 1,2,3 \}$, and may or may not contain each of $4$, $5$, or $6$. So, since each of those last three either may or may not be in those sets, there are $2^3 = 8$ such sets.